# pwd alias causing infinite loop in UNIX (bash)

Tags: bash, unix, alias, pwd

I have an alias, dir, which works fine using $(pwd) to show me the current directory I'm in:

```
alias dir='echo -e ${color1}jarvis: ${color2}you are currently in the ${color3}$(pwd)${color2} directory, sir.${NC}'
```

I would rather this alias be pwd, or have an identical one for pwd (so i can use dir or pwd to get the exact same response), but I seem to end up in an infinite loop everytime I try alias pwd=dir or

```
alias pwd='echo -e ${color1}jarvis: ${color2}you are currently in the ${color3}$(pwd)${color2} directory, sir.${NC}'
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alias pwd='echo -e ${color1}jarvis: ${color2}you are currently in the ${color3}$(\pwd)${color2} directory, sir.${NC}'
```

Backslash in `\pwd` avoids the alias.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, the environment variable `PWD` is always kept current. `pwd` is the shell built-in you shadowed with your alias, and `/bin/pwd` is always around in case it's 1984.

Comment: while informative, I don't see this as useful in regards to my question.

Comment: Instead of hard-coded path - `/bin/pwd`, you could `command pwd`... `command` is a shell built-in, which finds the first matching path of `pwd` binary (similar to `which`) & runs that.

Comment: @CommanderCody, No, it's actually useful. `alias pwd='echo -e ${color1}jarvis: ${color2}you are currently in the ${color3}$PWD${color2} directory, sir.${NC}'`

Comment: oh I see what you meant. I thought you were just explaining the differences between them... didn't put 2 and 2 together to see I could use PWD. I'll give it a shot tomorrow, along with the other answer.